# Singularity zero-width gutters

Tags: drupal-theming, singularitygs

I'm working on setting up an Omega 4 subtheme with no gutters?

Have tried several things including:

```
$gutters: 0;
```

and

```
$gutters: 0px;
```

in my `_grid.scss` file but doesn't seem to work.

Have also tried giving each div a percentage width in my .scss files (eg 25% for four columns) but still ends up with gutters between the first & second and the  second & third columns.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if youre using the new singularity 1.2+ you need to write

```
@include add-gutter(0);
```

There is also the possibility that your grid elements have higher priority `margin` option